# yii ajaxLink success and replaceWith

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

since three hours I don't found the error in jquery.
I try to refresh a div, after I've created a file

**Here is my View**

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Neuen Export erstellen',
    Yii::app()->createUrl('exporter/create' ),
    array(
        'data' => array(),
        'dataType'  => 'json',
        'type'      => 'POST',

        'complete'  => "js:function(html){
            $('#export-grid').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        }",

        'success'   => "js:function(html){
            $('#export-grid').replaceWith();
        }"

    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'c2a_gray alignright',
        'style' => 'font-size: 12px',
    )
);
?>
```

** My Controller **

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    // createfile();...
    // do some stuff
    $this->renderPartial('//users//exporter//_tmo', true, true);
}
```

**complete** Option works in ajaxLink function very well
but if I put **alert(html)** inside **complete** I got "Object object"

I don't know how to update export-grid with the new content.

please help me!
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you try to alert html then it will return Object.
Please try **alert(html.responseText)**.